# Structure of my app with different functions

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am creating a sports calculator app that will contain 5 plus different calculators.I am redesigning the UI from version one and using a bottom navigation bar, on that bar i have home, favourites and more. This is the structure...

```
Home
 Cacl 1 
 Cacl 2
 Cacl 3
 and so on

Favourites
 Open any favourited calcs

More
 This will contain settings info and buy premium
```

So i was wandering how should i open the calcs, should i have them as fragments or should i open them as new activities. And should i have the bottom nav there once one has been opened. I currently have home,favourites and more as fragments.
So how should i open the calculators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to open clac in fragments because when you add fragments in your code the app  is light weight and in future if u add something or update your app , it is easy for u to update it . but if you add activity in your app, your app may be bulkier for OS

(https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/5t3s5r/help_me_understand_when_to_use_fragments_vs/) use this

Comment: Thankyou! Is there anyway to hide the bottom bar when i open the calc fragments?

Comment: yes just set the visibility  of the bottom bar = "invisible" or "gone" ,